# I need to insert a custom Glyph

Tags: html, css

I used Icomoon to create a special glpyh for a logo so it will always display in emails, but I cant figure out how to get it to display...  I linke the font in my CSS by using

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Cog";
    src: url(http://oddmachine.com/links/Cog.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

The code I recieved from icofont was U+e600

HTML:

```
<span style="font-family: Cog;">&#e600;</span>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Are you trying to include this character/font in emails you are sending?

Comment: I just want to use the character, yes.  Similar to like you would with any other special character.

Comment: How are you adding that CSS to the email?  Most emails clients only like inline CSS.  This may not be possible in an email.  See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I'm using a <style> tag.  I'm testing it in a normal browser window though, so it should display anyway, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you didn't use the url correct. Try

```
src: url('http://oddmachine.com/links/Cog.ttf') format("truetype");
```

Comment: I think you're right, but the glyph is still not displaying.

Comment: I just looked up the icomoon help page and they say that everything you need to make ti work is in the package u got from them (including the css and html) may i see what u got with it?

Comment: Wont be able to help u with that, didn't get that far in college just yet.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  I was thinking I could use a character code to insert the Icon, but rather I had to create a class and use that to display the character.  I was searching in the wrong places the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one glyph in your .ttf you might want to try including it as a data uri rather than making a request @font-face

Check out this page with some explanation.
https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

If you're including the entire font-set then I wouldn't recommend doing this, as it will make your email so large it will truncate some clients.